# Binary And Alternate Representation Transforming

Tags: virus, malware, representation, virus-definitions

In [this publication](http://www.cacs.louisiana.edu/~walenste/pubs/2007-iciw-walenstein-mathur-chouchane-lakhotia.pdf) about Metamorphic viruses i have found this classification:

> Metamorphic malware may be either a ***binary-transformer*** or an ***alternate-representation-transformer***. The former class transforms the binary image that is executed, 
>   whereas the latter class carries its code in a higher level representation, which is used for 
>   transformation.

I did not found a precise definition of these two terms. I would like to know if is there a generic definition for each one, or a generic context to introduce the classification in my dissertation.

Thanks all.

Comment: very good paper `Arun Lakhotia` is champion in this filed. +1 to question. will answer you... btw, Which university?

Comment: University of Sannio, Italy.

Comment: is cisis -1213 holding in your university?

Comment: Do you intend my supervisor professor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More common term for **Binary-Transformer** is  `Binary Code Obfuscation` or simple `Binary Obfuscation`  (plays an essential role in evading malware static analysis and detection). Some anthers also use term `Post-compilation obfuscation`[*]. Term `Binary Obfuscation` also used in reverse engineering for innocent purpose (to recover source file).[[1]](http://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-17/dc-17-presentations/defcon-17-sean_taylor-binary_obfuscation.pdf)[[2]](http://www.utd.edu/~hamlen/cs6V81fa12/mimimorphism.pdf)[[3]](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/solar/papers/obf-signal.pdf)

Whereas, for **Alternate-Representation-Transformer** term `Assembly Level Obfuscation`, `Source Code Obfuscation`( or `Source Obfuscation`) you can use `Mnemonic Level Obfuscation`, `Code Obfuscation`.

[Read this sort article](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/assembler-obfuscation/assembler-obfuscation-code.asp) to find useful common terms.

(but I am not sure for `Post-compilation obfuscation`)

---

Paper Writing is not exact science. Different authors use different(rare) words to prevent probability of match. Many time my papers/journal rejected only due to presentation, but not because of technical flaw.

Comment: Thanks very much. Clear and exhaustive answer!